# Media query for fullscreen

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, fullscreen

I use the following media query to apply my CSS overrides in fullscreen mode:

```
@media (device-width: 100vw) and (device-height: 100vh) {
  .content {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

In works perfectly in Firefox but very unreliable in Chrome (both latest versions on Windows 7 x64). I can try to apply my overrides only when not in fullscreen mode but need to invert the query. So my questions are:

1. Should Chrome support the query?
2. How do I negate it (logical not)?

**p.s.**

My `viewport` is declared like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the opposite on Linux : this media query works in Chrome, doesn't work on Firefox

Answer (score 13):

Use new css features [display-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode)

```css
@media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
  .content {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```

Also avoid using `!important` as it's a [bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)

You can negate @media rules with `not`. Details on this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Negating_a_feature_with_not).

Comment: Question asks also how to negate it!?

Answer (score 5):

It might be less elegant, but more robust, to listen to the full screen event, then perhaps add an `is-fullscreen` class to the body so you can write your rule like this:

```
body.is-fullscreen .content { padding...
```

For example:

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('is-fullscreen', document.fullscreenEnabled);
});
```

This event has vendor-prefixed versions, so make sure you're using the one(s) you need.